# Combining XML nodes with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an API I'm currently using SOAP calls to and it is outputting an XML file. Where I'm running into trouble is putting the file into a table for easy reading. The biggest issue is that the asset.device and corresponding asset.os are not wrapped in anything.

The output is along the lines of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DeviceAssetInfoExport>
  <asset.device>
    <asset.device.id>123</asset.device.id>
    ...
  </asset.device>
  <asset.os>
    <asset.os.reportedos>abc</asset.os.reportedos>
    ...
  <asset.os>
  <asset.device>
    <asset.device.id>321</asset.device.id>
    ...
  </asset.device>
  <asset.os>
    <asset.os.reportedos>cba</asset.os.reportedos>
    ...
  <asset.os>
</DeviceAssetInfoExport>
```

The desired output is an html table like:

```
<html>
<body>
  <h2>Servers</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>OS</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>home.co</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

My current attempt at this is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" >
<xsl:template match="DeviceAssetInfoExport">
    <h2>Servers</h2>
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="gray">
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>OS</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="asset.device | asset.os"/>
        </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="asset.device | asset.os">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="asset.device.longname"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="asset.device.uri"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="asset.os.reportedos"/> - <xsl:value-of select="asset.os.osarchitecture"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately the output I receive from this places the asset.os.reportedos Information on its own row in the table. It is in the correct third position, its just not on the correct row with the device info.

If there is anything I can do to make my desired outcome more clear please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: I can't figure out what your question is. First you say that the desired output is [some XML], then you say you want an HTML table. And your input does not have the nodes you refer to in your XSLT, e.g. `asset.device.longname`. Why don't you show us a minimal - but **complete** - example of the input XML you are working with, along with the actual output you want to see at the end of the XSL transformation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I was split in my initial issue presentation, I felt that if I could get the XML in a more useful format that I could achieve my desired result, but it makes more sense to just get straight to the resolution. If its still not clear let me know.

Comment: I suspect you want the table to show the actual values (currently missing from your output), not their labels. If so, please edit your input to show say two complete records, with recognizable values, and adjust your expected output accordingly.

Comment: You are correct and I have made the suggested edits. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this can get you started:

**Input XML**

```
<DeviceAssetInfoExport>
  <asset.device>
    <asset.device.id>123</asset.device.id>
  </asset.device>
  <asset.os>
    <asset.os.reportedos>abc</asset.os.reportedos>
  </asset.os>
  <asset.device>
    <asset.device.id>456</asset.device.id>
  </asset.device>
  <asset.os>
    <asset.os.reportedos>def</asset.os.reportedos>
  </asset.os>
</DeviceAssetInfoExport>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/DeviceAssetInfoExport">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Servers</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>OS</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="asset.device"/>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="asset.device">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="asset.device.id"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::asset.os[1]/asset.os.reportedos"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>Servers</h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>OS</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>abc</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>456</td>
            <td>def</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: michael, thank you very much for taking the time to help me clarify my desired goal and resolve the issue. The following-sibling attribute is exactly what I needed, I wasn't even aware of its existence.

Comment: @TomMcDonald You're welcome. Please note: `following-sibling` is an **axis**, not an attribute. Terminology is important.